# CentOS 64bit RPM with 32bit dependencies

Tags: linux, 64-bit, centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I have a helper rpm package which is used to install the necessary dependencies in order for some software to work; the problem is that the dependency packages required are the 32bit ones, which can't be installed on CentOS 64bit without the `--setopt=protected_multilib=false` flag.

To manually install the dependencies I'd just run:

`# yum install --setopt=protected_multilib=false libXrandr.i686`

`# yum install --setopt=protected_multilib=false gtk2.i686`

`# yum install --setopt=protected_multilib=false libXtst.i686`

This would correctly install the 32bit version of the packages.

The problem appears when installing the helper package directly, as it seems there's no way to force --setopt=protected_multilib=false for the dependencies.

When trying to install the package (locally, using `yum --nogpgcheck --setopt=protected_multilib=false localinstall centos_helper-0-0.x86_64.rpm`) I get the following error:

```
Examining centos_helper-0-0.x86_64.rpm: centos_helper-0-0.x86_64
Marking centos_helper-0-0.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dattobackup.com
 * extras: mirror.metrocast.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.dattobackup.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package centos_helper.x86_64 0:0-0 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr.i686 for package: centos_helper-0-0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gtk2.i686 for package: centos_helper-0-0.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXtst.i686 for package: centos_helper-0-0.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: centos_helper-0-0.x86_64 (/centos_helper-0-0.x86_64)
           Requires: gtk2.i686
Error: Package: centos_helper-0-0.x86_64 (/centos_helper-0-0.x86_64)
           Requires: libXrandr.i686
Error: Package: centos_helper-0-0.x86_64 (/centos_helper-0-0.x86_64)
           Requires: libXtst.i686
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This is the same error I get when trying to install the dependencies by hand without the protected_multilib=false flag.

The .spec file I'm using to create the package has the following content:

```
Summary: CentOS helper file
Name: centos_helper
Version: 0
Release: 0
License: Public
Group: Applications/System
Requires: libXrandr.i686,gtk2.i686,libXtst.i686
%description
Installer CentOS helper package
%files
```

Any way to have the dependencies correctly install?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/ArchDependencies
I prefer referencing sonames myself, that way yum will look up what dependancy to install.
I've had major CentOS upgrades failing because if this.

This if for recent RPM versions only : 4.6 or so. If you're on something older :

Requires: real-soname.so.1()(64bit), real-soname.so.1, packagename

From memory, you might need a tweak.

Comment: Using so's is the more elegant solution to this, but I was hoping to avoid having to maintain that list as it is pretty long; this was the reason why I went with packages, as some packages contain a lot of the needed so's.

But I'll make a test marking libraries as dependencies instead of packages.